# Finding neighboring coordinates on offset tile map

Tags: objective-c, math, coordinates, tile

I have a grid of hexagonal tiles. Every other row is slightly offset for visual reasons. Imagine a player touches any tile - I need to compare the coordinate of that tile, with any tile they touch next so that I can ensure they're right next to each other.

[image]

If the grid had no offset, I could simply ensure we were within 1 x and 1 y coordinate, but that fails in certain scenarios here.

I can get extremely close - the following code works in all cases, but still allows coordinates 3,2 and 4,3 to count as neighbors, among others with a similar mathematical relationship.

```
int diffX = abs(newCoord.x - lastCoord.x);
int diffY = abs(newCoord.y - lastCoord.y);

// Never allow jumping rows
if( diffY > 1 || diffX > 1 ) return false;

// Allow same columns
if( diffX == 0 || diffY == 0 ) return true;

return false;
```

A friend had an idea about combining the coordinates into single numbers and ensuring the neighbor was within a certain amount, but that fails for several combinations as well.

Comment: This is more thorough than I could possibly explain: http://www.redblobgames.com/grids/hexagons/

Comment: Wow that looks like an amazing resource. Thanks! It's a lot to sort through though... I'll see what I can extract